# vuejs multiple single file components with one lodash throttle function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash, vuex

I have a single file component as below.

[image]

[image: v]

What it does it is, once you enter data it validates the person with the backend using an axios call written in a vuex action. This component is repeated multiple times. I have written a lodash throttle function to limit the validation requests in each components and it works fine.

The problem is lodash throttle function limit is only applicable within the component and once the start data entering 2nd component 1st components lodash throttle limit is not applicable. it fires the axios request.

How can I write a global lodash throttle function limit queries across components?

Note that the same vuex function is being called to validate the data across all components. The current vuex action code is as follows. The lodash throttle doesn't work for the below code.

```
 validateData({ dispatch }) {
    throttle(async function() {
      dispatch("validateDataFromServer");
    }, 25000)();
  },


  async validateDataFromServer({ commit, state }) {

   //The actual axios call goes here.

  }
```

Comment: Can't you just move the throttle to the vuex store action ?

Comment: @PascalLamers: Yeah tried but it didn't work

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer below ? What doesn't work ? Any errors ?

Comment: I added a working example to my answer, please take a look and let me know

Comment: @PascalLamers: Let me check and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try creating a throttled function given the vuex action you want to throttle and then use the returned, throttled function within the vuex store as action itself. This way the throttled function should be global to all components. 
(**tested ! see example below**)

```js
// store.js
import { throttle } from "lodash";

const actions = {
  validateDataFromServer : throttle(async function ({ commit, state}) {

    //The actual axios call goes here.

  }, 25000)
}
```

### Working Example

Since OP was running into problems , I created a quick live example. 
In the example I have multiple instances of a button which triggeres a vuex action on click. The vuex action itself is throttled through lodash and nomatter which button I click, the method will be throttled, like globally and will only fire every 10 seconds (in this example).

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-sunset-dop3y

Comment: Amazing stuff! Thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help !